# Ciclo for de matlab en python

Tags: python, matlab

Estoy haciendo este ciclo for de matlab a python
Matlab:

```
for j=1:length(theta)
     th=theta(j);
     aa=[exp(-1j*(2-n)*pi*sin(th)) ]
     y(j)=w*aa;
```

python:

```
for i in range(len(theta)):
th=theta[i]
aa=np.transpose([np.exp(-1j*(2-n)*np.pi*np.sin(th))])
```

Pero no sé como hacer la última línea en python, es decir: `y(j)=w*aa;`
Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que w es una constante, el código queda de la siguiente forma

```
for i in range(len(theta)):
th=theta[i]
aa=np.transpose([np.exp(-1j*(2-n)*np.pi*np.sin(th))])
y[i]=w*aa
```